# click btn toggleClass and change text with jQuery

Tags: jquery

Im working on some contentblocks which need to toggle when i click a button. It does the work right now but however the text wont change on my button when its focused or active and the content is toggled. See my code below (also it says uncaught syntax error: unexpected identifier).

```js
$(".mobile-tab").click(function() {
  $(this).parent().children(".content").toggleClass("open", function() {
    if ($(this).parent().children(".content").hasClass("open")) {
      $(this).parent().children(".mobile-tab").children(".symbol").text("Sluiten -");
    } else {
      $(this).removeClass("open").parent().children(".mobile-tab").children(".symbol").text("Lees meer +");
    }

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="entity entity-field-collection-item field-collection-item-field-tabs clearfix" about="/field-collection/field-tabs/15" typeof="">
 

<div class="title">
  <div class="field field-name-field-titel-event field-type-text field-label-hidden"><div class="field-items"><div class="field-item even">Programma</div></div></div>  </div>
  <div class="content">
      
 <div class="field field-name-field-inhoud field-type-text-with-summary field-label-hidden"><div class="field-items"><div class="field-item even">
<p>some randowm content</p>
</div></div></div>   </div>

<div class=" mobile-tab">
 
 <div class="symbol">Lees meer +</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Hopefully if get the right answer,

Regards Martijn

Comment: Please add your html code

Comment: On request:
<div class="field field-name-field-titel-event field-type-text field-label-hidden">
    <div class="field-items">
        <div class="field-item even">Programma</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="content">
    <div class="field field-name-field-inhoud field-type-text-with-summary field-label-hidden">
        <div class="field-items">
            <div class="field-item even"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class=" mobile-tab"><div class="symbol">Lees meer +</div></div>

Comment: To state the obvious. If you create a [mcve] we could get a picture of what's wrong. What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've removed some of your code since it was not needed at all.

Look at the example below, it now changes your text of `symbol`

```js
$(".mobile-tab").click(function() {
  $(this).parent().find(".content").toggleClass("open");
  if ($(this).prev(".content").hasClass("open") == true) {
    $(this).find(".symbol").text("Sluiten -");
  } else {
    $(this).find(".symbol").text("Lees meer +");
  }
});
```

```css
.content {
  display: none;
}

.content.open {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="entity entity-field-collection-item field-collection-item-field-tabs clearfix" about="/field-collection/field-tabs/15" typeof="">


  <div class="title">
    <div class="field field-name-field-titel-event field-type-text field-label-hidden">
      <div class="field-items">
        <div class="field-item even">Programma</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="field field-name-field-inhoud field-type-text-with-summary field-label-hidden">
      <div class="field-items">
        <div class="field-item even">
          <p>some randowm content</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class=" mobile-tab">

    <div class="symbol">Lees meer +</div>
  </div>
</div>
<br><br>
<div class="entity entity-field-collection-item field-collection-item-field-tabs clearfix" about="/field-collection/field-tabs/15" typeof="">


  <div class="title">
    <div class="field field-name-field-titel-event field-type-text field-label-hidden">
      <div class="field-items">
        <div class="field-item even">Programma</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="field field-name-field-inhoud field-type-text-with-summary field-label-hidden">
      <div class="field-items">
        <div class="field-item even">
          <p>some randowm content</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class=" mobile-tab">

    <div class="symbol">Lees meer +</div>
  </div>
</div>
<br><br>
<div class="entity entity-field-collection-item field-collection-item-field-tabs clearfix" about="/field-collection/field-tabs/15" typeof="">


  <div class="title">
    <div class="field field-name-field-titel-event field-type-text field-label-hidden">
      <div class="field-items">
        <div class="field-item even">Programma</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="field field-name-field-inhoud field-type-text-with-summary field-label-hidden">
      <div class="field-items">
        <div class="field-item even">
          <p>some randowm content</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class=" mobile-tab">

    <div class="symbol">Lees meer +</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Carsten what will be happen when I have multiple content divisions like this?

Comment: Updated, take a look. Btw kinda bad to mark a answer then remove it again.

Comment: Well i think you understand me wrong, this is what exally going on in my page:

div
-title
-content
-mobile-tab

div
-title
-content
-mobile-tab

div
-title
-content
-mobile-tab

div
-title
-content
-mobile-tab

So i have multiple same divisions with the same classes etc on my page, now when i click lees meer + or sluiten - every division will do the same included the text is changing. When I click the button the for close the button text wont change back to lees meer +.

Comment: Look at the snippet again

Answer (score 1):

The first issue with your code is that you're providing a callback function to the `toggleClass()` method when it does not have one. That call is synchronous, so you can just place the `if` statement after it.

Secondly, your DOM traversal is not quite right, and will be affected by the removal of the above function. To fix it you can use `siblings()` to get the `.content` element, and just `find()` the child `.symbol`, like this:

```js
$(".mobile-tab").click(function() {
  var $content = $(this).siblings(".content").toggleClass("open");
  var $symbol = $(this).find('.symbol');
  $symbol.text($content.hasClass("open") ? 'Sluiten -' : 'Lees meer +');
});
```

```css
.content { display: none; }
.content.open { display: block; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class>
  <div class="field field-name-field-titel-event field-type-text field-label-hidden">
    <div class="field-items">
      <div class="field-item even">Programma</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="field field-name-field-inhoud field-type-text-with-summary field-label-hidden">
      <div class="field-items">
        <div class="field-item even">Content</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="mobile-tab">
    <div class="symbol">Lees meer +</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var btnText = ["Lees meer +", "Sluiten -"];

$(".mobile-tab").click(function() {

  var $me = $(this); // Hello, it's me
  var $content = $(this).closest(".parentHellYeah").find(".content");

  $content.toggleClass("open");
  
  var isOpen = $content.hasClass("open");
  $me.text( btnText[ +isOpen ] );

  
});
```

```css
.parentHellYeah .content{
  display:none;
}
.parentHellYeah .content.open{
  display:block;
}

.mobile-tab{
  background: gold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="parentHellYeah">

  <div class="field field-name-field-titel-event field-type-text field-label-hidden">
    <div class="field-items">
      <div class="field-item even">Programma</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="content">
    <div class="field field-name-field-inhoud field-type-text-with-summary field-label-hidden">
      <div class="field-items">
        <div class="field-item even">CONTENT?</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="mobile-tab">
    <div class="symbol">Lees meer +</div>
  </div>

</div>
```